# How does the ionic radius influence the ion's interaction?

Tags: particle-physics, interactions, structure-formation

What can we deduce about an ion, its interaction or the structure it is in, based on the ionic radius?

My understanding of the concept of the ionic radius is that these are seen almost as having a physical hard shell, but what does that truly mean?

Is it a way of picturing the distance up to which they can interact with other particles?